# Timeserial not recognized built in function in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to implement an SQL query that gets records between today's fixed timing 18:00 and yesterday's fixed timing 18:00 based on a Date time column that I have in my table.

I tried this query

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE()
SELECT * 
FROM mytab
WHERE datetimecolumn Between @today-1 + TimeSerial(18,0,0) 
                              And @today   + TimeSerial(18,0,0)
```

But, it's throwing an error `Timeserial is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Any ideas please?

Comment: That's because it's not a function in SQL Server. Seems to be an MSAccess function?

Comment: The [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql) documents the available functions on date and time types.

Comment: Probably just easiest to use `dateadd(hour, ...)` if always whole hours (-6 or +18). Minutes would be easy also. The message should have been easy to figure out on your own though.

Comment: BTW You shouldn't be doing `datetimecolumn  Between '2022-01-02 18:00:00' AND '2022-01-03 18:00:00'` - you should use 
`datetimecolumn >= '2022-01-02 18:00:00' AND datetimecolumn < '2022-01-03 18:00:00'`

Comment: @MartinSmith Why is `<` and `>` better than `between`?

Comment: @Shmiel The suggestion is to use `>= and <`. Because `BETWEEN` is the equivalent of  `>= and <=` - this would mean that any value with exactly `18:00:00` would end up being reported twice when the query is run twice for two consecutive days,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to use the DATEADD() function to add the time to the date you want.  In this example, it subtracts 6 hours from the first number to get 18:00 yesterday, and then adds 18 hours to get 18:00 today.

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE();
SELECT * FROM mytab WHERE datetimecolumn Between DATEADD(hour,-6,@today) And DATEADD(hour,18,@today);
```

Comment: That's correct Martin,  I edited it to use the @today variable so that it doesn't capture the time

Comment: You will now hit another issue. `The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.` you could change `DECLARE @today date = GETDATE();` to `DECLARE @today datetime = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);`